Determine when Parent is Flex or Grid to specify the typescript types autosuggestion
I am using @emotion/styled and I've encountered an issue I cannot resolve. I have two styled components, <Flex> and <Grid>.
What I'm trying to achieve is for <Flex> to detect whether it's nested inside another <Flex> or <Grid>, so it can adjust its types and behavior accordingly. Specifically:

If <Flex> is nested inside a <Grid>, I want it to behave as a
<GridItem> also.
If <Flex> is nested inside another <Flex>, I
want it to behave as a <FlexItem> also.

I know that I can handle this with a flag prop, like <Flex parent="Flex"> or <Flex parent="Grid">, but I'd like to avoid this solution. I'm looking for a way to automatically detect the parent component and adjust the behavior dynamically.
Is there a way to achieve this?
Here is my code:
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

interface FlexProps {
  direction?: "row" | "row-reverse" | "column" | "column-reverse";
  wrap?: "nowrap" | "wrap" | "wrap-reverse";
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

interface GridProps {
  columns?: number;
  rows?: number;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

interface FlexItemProps {
  grow?: number;
  shrink?: number;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

interface GridItemProps {
  column?: number;
  row?: number;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const StyledFlex = styled.div<FlexProps>((props: FlexProps) => {
  return {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: props.direction,
    flexWrap: props.wrap,
  };
});

const StyledGrid = styled.div<GridProps>((props) => {
  return {
    display: "grid",
    gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${props.columns}, 1fr)`,
    gridTemplateRows: props.rows ? `repeat(${props.rows}, 1fr)` : undefined,
  };
});

const StyledFlexItem = styled.div<FlexItemProps>(({ grow, shrink }) => {
  return {
    flexGrow: grow,
    flexShrink: shrink,
  };
});

const StyledGridItem = styled.div<GridItemProps>(({ column, row }) => {
  return {
    gridColumn: column,
    gridRow: row,
  };
});

export function Flex(props: FlexProps): JSX.Element {
  return <StyledFlex {...props}>{props.children}</StyledFlex>;
}

export function Grid(props: GridProps): JSX.Element {
  return <StyledGrid columns={props.columns || 12} {...props}>{props.children}</StyledGrid>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Grid>
        <Flex></Flex> {/* I want the Flex to know that is nested to Grid */} 
      </Grid>

      <Flex>
        <Flex></Flex> {/* I want the Flex to know that is nested to another Flex */}
      </Flex>
    </>
  );
}

